# Transferring iOS app with iCloud enabled

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

When going to transfer my iOS app to another developer, I got this message

```
You can't transfer this app because of the following reasons:
iCloud enabled
You can only transfer apps that aren’t iCloud enabled.
```

[Deleting and Transferring Apps Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/TransferringAndDeletingApps.html)

The documentation states:

```
Make sure the app uses only technology and content that can be transferred.
No version of the app can use an iCloud entitlement.
```

Since a version of my app used iCloud, is there literally no way I can transfer it? If there is a way, how should I proceed?

Comment: How about handing over the developer account as well?

Comment: How about handing over the developer account as well?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The app must be deleted and re-created with a new SKU/Bundle ID.

Remove the app from sale by going to Pricing > Select Territories > Deselect All

Delete the app under More (to the right of Prerelease, Pricing etc) > Delete App

Create the app under the developer account as a new app with the same name with a new SKU/Bundle ID.

This will delete any reviews/ratings, gamecenter data, iCloud data, and any other data linked to that app. You'll have to recreate any in app purchases you had.

Comment: Does it mean that the previous users can update the app? Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately no. Users must re-download the app as if it was new.

Comment: I'm actually going to stop using iCloud for this very lame reason. If you're ever thinking of transferring the app eventually (buy-out?) then don't use iCloud to begin with.

Comment: Had to remove iCloud Keychain usage from my app before I publish it for this very reason. Lame.

Comment: If you have a popular app that has been around for a long time this will destroy your search rankings and reviews.

Comment: Should we still do this in 2021 for a solution? Is there still no other solution?

Comment: This is so bad! Why does this criteria exist? What are the security reasons?

Answer (score 10):

WARNING: Never use iCloud Entitlements in an app. It's not worth it because it makes your app untransferable and therefore unsaleable forever!

I had enabled iCloud entitlements in some previous build to play around with NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore, and now I can never transfer that app... This is so so so very bad. I have an Android version of the app, ran into no issues with Google Play.

Answer (score 2):

**For June 2022+**: Apple has updated the rules in 2022. Now you can transfer your app the regular way even if it uses iCloud. They write about limitations in their [documentation](https://help.apple.com/app-store-connect/#/deved688524f) now in "Apps Using iCloud" paragraph.

Answer (score 1):

Same here. I was just using NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore to allow the user to share some settings across devices. Now all my users who paid for the app will not receive any more updates, my 4.5 star ratings will be gone, etc. I am super frustrated and this will cost me a lot of money.

I have written an article about his on [medium.com](https://georg.howen.de/why-ios-developers-should-never-use-icloud-in-their-apps-65aa303e4052), so feel free to share it in your professional networks if you feel this could help fellow developers to not run into this trap.